# Facebook crawler not fetching image for share

Tags: facebook, share

We have a [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) site and Facebook share button on it, but the shared image is not loaded although it is defined in the header.

When we view the source code everything looks fine, but Facebook developer tools shows it cannot load the image. This is the Facebook developer link:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kuca-za-odmor-cvetkovic.hr%2F

This normally used to work and simply stopped a few weeks ago. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I’m just getting “Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received” right now in debug tool, when I trigger a new scrape.

Comment: Yes, i'm also getting the same thing but with this message "Object at URL 'http://www.kuca-za-odmor-cvetkovic.hr/' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided." If you take a look at source code, both tags are there.

Comment: That’s just a subsequent error, resulting from the first one – your page is too slow, so Facebook is canceling the request after a while. So see to it that you get your page to respond faster.

Comment: I use the same custom CMS for 200 similar sites on the same infrastrucutre and works fine on all others...

Comment: When I go to http://www.kuca-za-odmor-cvetkovic.hr/ in my browser, it takes 20 seconds before the first byte arrives … If that page is actually faster at your own location, then I’d suggest you go talk to your server/network admin, and let them figure out why it might be loading so slow when requested from other parts of the world.

Comment: Thanks, CBroe, the site performance was the problem!